# How to increase the performance of logging in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, log4j2

I have multiple logs in my elasticsearch plugin app which will be logged during ingest and search.

I want to reduce the time taken to log the events in all log files when multiple ingest or bulk ingest happens. Same for search as well.

What should I do in elasticsearch [log4j2.properties](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/distribution/src/config/log4j2.properties) in order to achieve it?

Will Async Logger works for my scenario? How should I use [Async](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html) Logger in the ES log4j2.properties file?